# ¿Cómo separar palabras de una lista de frases de un diccionario?

Tags: python, lista

Cómo escribo una función en python que pasado una lista de frases como argumento, retorne un diccionario
de palabras, por ejemplo:

Entrada: [‘Mauricio ama los gatos’, ‘Luis ama los perros’,
‘Maria prefiere los caballos, pero ama perros y gatos’]

Salida esperada: [‘mauricio’, ‘ama’, ‘los’, ‘gatos’, ‘luis’, ‘perros’,
‘maria’, ‘prefiere’, ‘caballos,’ ,’pero’, ‘y’]

Esta es una respuesta a esta pregunta dejo el código en comentarios

Este código lo que hace es recibir frases en una lista e imprimir palabras sin repetir ejemplo si ingresas, "amor es igual a tiempo sin tiempo no hay amor" imprimiría : amor es igual a tiempo sin no hay

Comment: Que haz intentado hasta ahora para lograr eso?

Comment: Lo he probado con la función .split() pero no me permite hacerlo en un diccionario

Comment: O sea intentaste `dict(tulista.split())`? Te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta y agregues ahí el código que no te funciona, así es más facil ayudarte y tu pregunta es mejor recibida por la comunidad c:

Comment: La salida esperada no es un diccionario, si no una lista. Estas seguro que lo que te piden es un diccionario?

Comment: No sé qué entiendes por diccionario... La palabra diccionario en Python tiene un sentido muy técnico (es un tipo particular). Quizás usas la palabra diccionario en el sentido "de la calle", como una lista de palabras. Si lo que quieres es obtener las palabras sin repeticiones puedes usar un `set()` al que vayas añadiendo el resultado de cada `frase.split()`

Answer (score 0):

```
frases = ['Mauricio ama los gatos' , 'Luis ama los perros' , 'Maria prefiere 
los caballos, pero ama perros y gatos']
#usamos la variable espacio que contenga un str 
espacio = " "
#usamos la varible palabras juntas para contener las palabras unidas con.join
palabras_juntas = espacio.join(frases)
"""
se declara la variable nueva_lista para almacenar una lista de solo las 
palabras separadas
"""
nueva_lista = palabras_juntas.split()

palabras_sin_repetir=[]

#declaramos la funcion def
def frasepalabras_juntas():
    #recorremos la var nueva lista para selecionar las palabras
 for palabras in nueva_lista:
     """almacenamos en la var palabras_sin_repetir las palabras sin repetir 
        de la var nueva_lista"""
  if palabras not in palabras_sin_repetir:
      """si la palbra no exciste se agrega a la var palabras_sin_repetir
         palabras_sin_repetir.append(palabras)"""
          
frasepalabras_juntas()
#finalmente la magia 
print(palabras_sin_repetir)
```

Comment: ¿Esto es una respuesta a tu propia pregunta? No hay problema en que te autorespondas, pero deberías proporcionar una respuesta de mejor calidad, para que sea de utilidad a otros. Revisa el formato, que no es correcto (y en python eso sería un error de compilación), y explica un poco qué hace el tu solución, ya que las respuestas de solo código no son bienvenidas

Comment: Hola aprecio tu comentario en respuesta he comentado el codigo y este codigo lo que hace es recibe frases en una lista e imprime palabras sin repetir ejemplo si ingresas, "amor es igual a tiempo sin tiempo no hay amor" imprimiría : amor es igual a tiempo sin no hay